# can we convert the NSDecimal values to UIImage?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image, nsdecimalnumber

i am sending some data and UIImage(converting UIImage to NSData) sending to server, My client is giving back the response what we send.

But, Here my client giving the UIImage like the below format

```
FaceImage":[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,1,1,44,1,44,0,0,255,219,0,67,0,8,6,6,7,6,5,8,7,7,7,9,9,8,10,12,20,13,12,11,11,12,25,18,19,15,20,29,26,31,30,29,26,28,28,32,36,46,39,32,34,44,35,28,28,40,55,41,44,48,49,52,52,52,31,39,57,61,56,50,60,46,51,52,50,255,219,0,67,1,9,9,9,12,11,12,24,13,13,24,50,.................................................................]
```

i am tested the above one to test what we are getting by using this log

```
NSLog(@"testingImageView.image is =%@",[[[datadic valueForKey:@"FaceImage"] objectAtIndex:0] class]);
```

**Response is:**   testingImageView.image is =NSDecimal.

If it is NSData we can convert to UIImage, But here it is in decimal format.

My question is, can i convert it to UIImage? i.e., the decimal values to UIImage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your response contains all the image bytes as decimal numbers. (`255,216` is `FF,D8` in hex, which indicates the start of a JPEG image). The following code should work to create an `UIImage` from the array of numbers:

```
NSArray *array = [datadic objectForKey:@"FaceImage"];
NSMutableData *imageData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:[array count]];
uint8_t *imageBytes = [imageData mutableBytes];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    imageBytes[i] = [array[i] unsignedCharValue];
}
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDecimalNumber *myNSDecimalNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:myNSDecimal]; 
NSInteger myInt = [myNSDecimalNumber intValue];// convert nsdeimal to nsdecimal number and then to nsinteger

NSUInteger index = (NSUInteger)myInt;
NSData *payload = [NSData dataWithBytes:&index length:sizeof(index)];// convert nsinteger to nsdata

UIImageView *imgv = [[UIImageView alloc]
                     initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
imgv.image = [UIImage imageWithData:retrievedData];// converting into image th nsdata
[self.view addSubview:imgv];
```